# References broken when running external dll's as modules

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, dll, caliburn.micro

I'm trying my hand at writing a modular application using Caliburn micro using https://github.com/lukebuehler/Caliburn-Composite-Prototype as my guide.

However i'm having an issue that i'm sure comes down to my unfamiliarity with VS and the complex setups involved.

Basically i have a base application (Dashboard) which using Caliburn micro and overrides `SelectAssemblies` in order to load dll's (Which form my modules) from a subfolder called Modules.

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        var assemblies = base.SelectAssemblies();
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"Modules");
        var files = directory.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        //only load the the dlls that are from this namespace
        var modules = files.Where(f => f.Name.Contains("Dashboard"))
                            .Select(f => Assembly.LoadFile(f.FullName));
        return assemblies.Concat(modules);
    }
```

Now the problem comes from the fact that these dll's are the run by the main program (Dashboard) and all my references are then broken, DLL references are unable to be found unless i move them into the base directory of Dashboard and config files (such as those containing endpoints) are not found.

What i need to do is allow my modules to be self contained using whichever external lib's needed and config files, and then have dashboard know where to find these files. But i have no idea what i need to do to get this working.

I hope i'm explaining that correctly.

Comment: Is the Modules folder copied to your output folder? e.g. <project>/bin/Debug/Modules

Comment: The modules have a build location of /bin/debug/modules